# Timer on my kenmore model 911.93311010 won' t beep. How do i reset it?

Tags: oven, timer

How do I reset my Kenmore stove 911.93311010 timer to beep

Comment: Do you have the owner's manual? Try calling their technical support.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Dianne- Sadly, the [owners manual](https://www.searspartsdirect.com/manual/lgo232zpaf-000582/kenmore-91193311010-electric-range-parts) doesn't seem to include trouble shooting for this particular issue, nor any options on how to enable/disable this beep. Have you contacted Kenmore customer service to ask them for assistance?